Which functions / formulas can the "Sort and Filter" Function in Google Sheets be used with?
I am currently working on a really large spreadsheet for case law analysis. On the cases, I add "codes" (keywords) for qualitative analysis which I want to further analyze in the next step.
My current question is: how can I use the Sort and Filter function (not the FILTER function / formula that is entered into a cell, but the filter that can be added via the Data tab) successfully in combination with other formulas?
I've created a much simpler test sheet to illustrate the problem: Test sheet

Sheet 1: "Box_contents" --> The cases are "boxes" of fruit. Think of it as an order list.
Sheet 2: "Filter" --> All the fruit types that have been ordered, the number of occurences and the amount of boxes in which the fruit occurs at least once.

The setup / requirements:

One sheet contains a list with the box number and all the fruit ordered in that box.
On a different sheet, I need a list of all the fruit that have been ordered, the amount of it that has been ordered (overall occurences; one fruit can be ordered several times in one box) and the amount of boxes the fruit has been ordered in.
In this second sheet, I would like to be able to flexibly sort the listed fruit alphabetically or by frequency of occurences.

I've gotten as far as step #2. However, the sort and filter function does not work properly with the data provided. It just will not sort alphabetically or at all; with some columns, it will just add a few empty rows on top and then keep the rest of the data as it is.
Unfortunately, I can't find any information on the types of formulas the sort & filter function can be used with. E.g.: Does it not work with array formulas? Does it not work with data derived from other sheets? Does it not work with data derived from a formula?
If you have any advice* or links to sites with more info on the sort & filter function, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

*I'm also grateful for advice on how to create a cleaner solution to step #2 (other than creating a SPLIT and SPLIT/UNIQUE dataset). I'm unhappy with this approach. However, please keep in mind that this is just a simple test sheet; the actual project is much more complex (it has 10+ sheets with ~1000 columns in some of them). Quite a few formulas and functions don't actually work with that much data or the setup of the original project.
I've done research on the "sort and filter" function of Google Sheets, but I haven't found any information on which type of data  and/or formulas it can be used with.
Using sort & filter with any type of data that was just entered into the cells below, it works just fine.
I've also tried removing some of the columns in my original sheet and then checking whether the problem was connected to one specific formula (e.g. "FLATTEN", which I have to use in my original project), but the outcome was always the same.


Here's one alternative setup which you may adapt accordingly:
=let(Λ;map(Box_contents!B3:B;lambda(Σ;split(Σ;", ";)));Δ;tocol(Λ;3);
 sort(map(unique(Δ);lambda(Σ;hstack(Σ;countif(Δ;Σ);sum(byrow(Λ;lambda(x;if(countif(x;Σ)>0;1;)))))));xmatch(B1;A3:C3);if(C1="asc";1;)))



dropdown in Cell_B1 is created by selecting the validation range A3:C3; which inturn is used to feed what column to sort to the formula
dropdown in Cell_C1 has asc and desc as sort options
formula is in Cell_A4


Thank you for your suggestion! I will look into this and try the solution. I'm a bit hesitant as this might not be suitable for the original project due to its complexity, but I will try it out.

I've tried this for my test sheet and it is working nicely. Thank you very much for your time and effort. I would have preferred to work with the native "sort and filter" function since that is more accessible for other users and provides more possibilities, but this is a nice solution for now.

Filters with arrays
The sorting functionality of a filter does not function (lol) when used with formulae that output arrays  :(  This isn't specified in any documentation that I know of, but has been a known long-standing issue, one of those where you report the problem to Google so they can do nothing about it fix it.
So two work-arounds:

either build your own sorting device - rockinfreakshow's solution, which is simple and works wonderfully;
or, if you want to stick to the native filter, use formulae that don't deal with arrays. In your case, doing so solely with built-in functions seems like a tough approach, so the best option would be to use custom functions declared in a script. That is what this solution puts forward.

Disclaimer
Bear in mind that avoiding arrays means that the data will not populate automatically whenever new rows are added, so the formulae would have to be dragged down manually; and that it is probably slower, since whenever you re-sort your data a new formula will have to be computed for each cell. Buy here we go anyway.
Using custom functions
To do this, here are the steps:

on the 'Extensions' menu, click on 'Apps Script'. A new tab should open.
Erase all the "myFunction" stuff.
Copy and paste the following code:

// Modify the values below if necessary.
const sheetNameContent = "Box_contents";
const sheetNameFilter = "Filter";
// The column number of the orders (B = 2).
const columnContent = 2;
// The number of the first row of orders.
const firstRowContent = 3;

const sheetContent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                   .getSheetByName(sheetNameContent);
const sheetfilter  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                   .getSheetByName(sheetNameFilter);

/**
 * Returns the name of the fruit corresponding to a \
 * given index in the sorted list of all possible fruits.
 * 
 * @param {number} index - The 1-based index of the fruit.
 * @return {string} The name of the fruit.
 * @customfunction
 */
function FRUIT(index) {
  const fruits = [...new Set(sheetContent.getRange(firstRowContent, columnContent, 
                                                    sheetContent.getLastRow())
                                         .getValues()
                                         .flatMap(([basket]) => basket.split(', ')))
                  ].filter(fruit => fruit !== '');
  return fruits.sort()[index - 1];
}

/**
 * Returns the total number of times a given \
 * fruit has been ordered across all orders.
 * 
 * @param {string} referenceFruit - The name \
 * of the fruit to be counted.
 * @return {number} The number of total occurrences.
 * @customfunction
 */
function COUNTTOTAL(referenceFruit) {
  const totalCount = sheetContent.getRange(firstRowContent, columnContent, 
                                            sheetContent.getLastRow())
                                 .getValues()
                                 .flatMap(([basket]) => basket.split(', '))
                                 .reduce((count, fruit) =>
                        (fruit === referenceFruit ? ++count : count), 0);
  return totalCount;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of orders that contain a given fruit.
 * 
 * @param {string} fruit - The name of the fruit.
 * @return {number} The number of baskets.
 * @customfunction
 */
function COUNTBASKETS(fruit) {
  const basketsCount = sheetContent.getRange(firstRowContent, columnContent, 
                                            sheetContent.getLastRow())
                                 .getValues()
                                 .flatMap(([basket]) => [basket.split(', ')])
                                 .reduce((count, basket) => 
                        (basket.includes(fruit) ? ++count : count), 0);
  return basketsCount;
}


At the very top, modify the values of those constants if necessary (the name of the sheets, and the row and column number of your data).

Save the project, then click on 'Run'. You will have to accept some permissions.


Now you can use those functions as any other function. We just need one intermediate step:

in your "Filter" sheet, add a column to the left of the table (in your example, column A). Fill in this column with numbers from 1 to whatever. You can use some formula (like SEQUENCE) to populate it, as long as you then copy and paste only the values using ctrl + shift + V. The important thing being here that there are reference numbers that move around when re-ordering, so the custom functions can work properly.



In cell B4, enter the following formula:  =FRUIT(A4).

In cell C4, enter the following formula:  =COUNTTOTAL(B4).

In cell D4, enter the following formula:  =COUNTBASKETS(B4).

Drag each formula down its column to apply it to the other rows.



That's it! You're supposed to be able to use the filter now (if it doesn't work, try removing it and adding it again #IT). That said, I would personally stick to rockinfreakshow's solution, even if I don't understand their formulae  :p
N.B. I know you're not actually dealing with fruits; you can change the name of the functions in the script (or leave them as they are  #GoVegan).

Thank you for your time and effort! I will check out this solution properly as soon as I can (swamped with work rn). I'm not sure if this will work for my main project and I'm always a bit hesitant to include macros, since the project sheet is already very slow and lagging sometimes. But I'll make sure to check it out! And I'll #stayvegan, promise :-)
